# how to pay for goods with tokens ERC20

Tags: tokens, erc-20, testrpc-to-ropsten

my english is very bad.i am sorry. 
I found an example of an auction where you can pay with ethers. I would like to pay with ERC20 tokens. Please tell me how to do this in the `placeBID ()` and `FinalizeAuction ()` functions. I display it all through web3js on the browser. I also created my token and transferred them to all accounts via metamask. I am a noob in this thread. I run everything on the ropsten test environment. Thanks in advance.

AuctionBox.sol

```
pragma solidity 0.5.3;
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";

import "ballot_test.sol";



contract AuctionBox{


Auction[] public auctions; 





function createAuction (
    string memory _title,
    uint _startPrice,
    string memory _description
    ) public{
    // set the new instance
    Auction newAuction = new Auction(msg.sender, _title, _startPrice, _description);
    // push the auction address to auctions array
    auctions.push(newAuction);
}

function returnAllAuctions() public view returns(Auction[] memory){
    return auctions;
}
}





contract Auction {

TRC20 trc20;
using SafeMath for uint256;
//AuctionBox trc20;
address payable private owner; 
string title;
uint startPrice;
string description;

enum State{Default, Running, Finalized}
State public auctionState;

uint public highestPrice;
address payable public highestBidder;
mapping(address => uint) public bids;

/** @dev constructor to creat an auction
  * @param _owner who call createAuction() in AuctionBox contract
  * @param _title the title of the auction
  * @param _startPrice the start price of the auction
  * @param _description the description of the auction
  */

constructor(
    address payable _owner,
    string memory _title,
    uint _startPrice,
    string memory _description

    ) public {
    // initialize auction
    owner = _owner;
    title = _title;
    startPrice = _startPrice;
    description = _description;
    auctionState = State.Running;
}

modifier notOwner(){
    require(msg.sender != owner);
    _;
}

/** @dev Function to place a bid
  * @return true
  */

function placeBid() public payable notOwner returns(bool) {
    require(auctionState == State.Running);
    require(msg.value > 0);
    // update the current bid
    // uint currentBid = bids[msg.sender] + msg.value;
    uint currentBid = bids[msg.sender].add(msg.value);
    //uint currentBid = balanceOf[msg.sender];
    require(currentBid > highestPrice);
    // set the currentBid links with msg.sender
    bids[msg.sender] = currentBid;
    //balanceOf[msg.sender] = currentBid;
    // update the highest price
    highestPrice = currentBid;
    highestBidder = msg.sender;
    //trc20.transferFrom(msg.sender, owner, 100);
    return true;
}

function finalizeAuction() public{
    //the owner and bidders can finalize the auction.
    require(msg.sender == owner || bids[msg.sender] > 0);

    address payable recipiant;
    uint value;

    // owner can get highestPrice
    if(msg.sender == owner){
        recipiant = owner;
        value = highestPrice;
    }
    // highestBidder can get no money
    else if (msg.sender == highestBidder){
        recipiant = highestBidder;
        value = 0;
    }
    // Other bidders can get back the money 
    else {
        recipiant = msg.sender;
        value = bids[msg.sender];
    }
    // initialize the value
    bids[msg.sender] = 0;
    recipiant.transfer(value);
    //transfer(recipiant, 100);
    auctionState = State.Finalized;
}

/** @dev Function to return the contents od the auction
  * @return the title of the auction
  * @return the start price of the auction
  * @return the description of the auction
  * @return the state of the auction 
  */    

function returnContents() public view returns(        
    string memory,
    uint,
    string memory,
    State
    ) {
    return (
        title,
        startPrice,
        description,
        auctionState
    );
}
}
```

ballot_test.sol

```
pragma solidity 0.5.3;


contract TRC20{
     string public name;
     string public symbol;
     uint8 public decimals = 8;
     uint256 public totalSupply;

 mapping (address=> uint256) public balanceOf;
 mapping(address=> mapping(address=>uint256)) public allowance;

 event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
 event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 value);
 event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

 uint256 initialSupply = 1000000;
 string tokenName = 'CodeXpertToken';
 string tokenSymbol = 'CDX';



 constructor() public{

     totalSupply = initialSupply*10**uint256(decimals);
     balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
     name = tokenName;
     symbol = tokenSymbol;

 }

 function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal{

     //require(_to!=0x0);
     require(balanceOf[_from]>=_value);
     require(balanceOf[_to] + _value>=balanceOf[_to]);
     uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];

     balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
     balanceOf[_to] +=_value;
     emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
     assert(balanceOf[_from]+balanceOf[_to]==previousBalances);



 }

 function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public payable returns (bool success){
     _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
     return  true;
 }

 function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns(bool success){

     require(_value<= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);
     _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
     return true;
 }

 function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success){
     allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
     emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);

     return true;

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify `placeBid` like this:

```
function placeBid(uint amount) public notOwner returns(bool) {
    require(auctionState == State.Running);

    // update the current bid
    uint currentBid = bids[msg.sender].add(amount);
    require(currentBid > highestPrice);

    // set the currentBid links with msg.sender
    bids[msg.sender] = currentBid;

    // update the highest price
    highestPrice = currentBid;
    highestBidder = msg.sender;

    // Move to tokens to contract address
    trc20.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);

    return true;
}
```

Modifications:

- Pass amount of tokens as parameter
- Remove payable modifier
- Transfer tokens to contract address

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a question, how do I know if the sender has a token? how to contact the wallet where there are tokens? thanks.
I think that tokens are a contract, so to pay with tokens you need to refer to the contract that created the tokens. Am i right? in my code, I don’t refer specifically to the contract, but just import the file. Is this correct?

Comment: when I run the 'placeBid ()' function the error "Gas estimation failed
"

Comment: @malysh To obtain the token balance you call `trc20.balanceOf(<address>)`. A contract usualy don't do that since `trc20.transferFrom()` will fail if you don't have enough balance. If you want to use an ERC20 it is enough to include the interface, for example [OpenZeppelin's IERC20](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol), then assign the address to a variable `IERC20 token = 0x123412341234...;`. In order to use `transferFrom` the owner has to approve the contract address.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Sorry if the question is dumb. I deployed a TRC20 contract that creates tokens and deployed an AuctionBox contract that creates an auction. Can I use TRC20 tokens for an auction? I think I do not have access to these tokens through the Auction contract. You can check your placeBid () function where the error may be most likely, I tried but couldn’t (thanks. I still get the "Gas estimation errored" error when I run the placeBid () function

Comment: @malysh Did you call approve? In order to allow the contract to use your tokens you have to approve its address. Something like `trc20.approve(<auctionBoxAddress>, <amount>, { from: <tokensOwnerAddress> })`

Comment: I execute the approve() function through the token contract. But still there is a gas estimation error. Should I do  functionTransferFrom() after the approve functions? If I have to send me? To the contract?

Comment: Here is a nice answer with some detail about using approve+transferFrom https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/46458. If you have more doubts please create a new question and add solidity code and client code you are using to call it.

Comment: hello, I would appreciate if you look at my question. thanks. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79683/gas-estimation-failed-when-transferfrom-or-transfer