# Gas estimation fail

Tags: tokens, openzeppelin-contracts

I am using remix and ganache and metamask and I encounter a confusing error.
I compiled and deployed USDT at

> 0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7

on ganache with no problem. In order to do some test on it I wrote following contract in remix:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol";

contract testTether {
    
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
    IERC20 public token;

    constructor(IERC20 _token) public {
        token = _token;
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) public {
        token.safeTransfer(to, amount);
    }
}
```

when I try to call **transfer** function I get:

> Gas estimation failed:
> Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
> Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert SafeERC20: low-level call failed

what is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are probably specifying an `amount` larger than the balance of the `from` account.

Comment: @goodvibration Thanks for reply but no, it is not the problem and from account has sufficient **balance**. I am wondering if I should **approve** amount of token before transfer for owner? As I read [here](https://medium.com/ethex-market/erc20-approve-allow-explained-88d6de921ce9#:~:text=When%20using%20a%20decentralized%20exchange%20to%20sell%20ERC20%20tokens%2C%20there,which%20you%20want%20to%20sell.) for token exchange two transaction is needed.

Comment: You should `approve` before `transferFrom`, not before `transfer`.

Comment: As implemented `testTether.transfer` will transfer tokens from `testTether` contract balance. It doesn't move tokens from `msg.sender`.

Comment: @Ismael, Thanks, yes you are right. It was because of lack of enough **balance** in `testTether` contract. Is there any way to transfer token from one account to another directly using a smart contract function like my code above in a way that transaction fee be paid by `sender account` not smart contract?

Comment: @Kourosh It is possible the token's owner has to call `approve` with the contract address and amount to spend, then the contract can call `transferFrom` on behalf of the token's owner. See this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46457/send-tokens-using-approve-and-transferfrom-vs-only-transfer for more details.