# Calling a function[A] that in turn calls a function[B] from another Contract

Tags: transactions, contract-deployment, address.transfer, delegatecall

I have two Contracts, `Domain` and `Serial` deployed separately.

NOTE: Most of the code is ommited for simplicity.

```
 contract Serial {
    
       Domain DOMAIN; //Domain contract is imported and set by another function
    
       function payToSerial(string memory serialNumber, unit amount) public {
           address toAddr = serialToAddress(serialNumber) //We convert serial number to a valid address
           DOMAIN.transfer(toAddr, amount) //Use transfer() from *Domain* contract
       }            
     }  



 contract Domain {
       function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public {
          //does transfer under specific conditions,
       }
     }
```

When I call **transfer()** from `Domain` contract it works, sends the funds from my wallet to whichever address I had specified.

However, when I call **payToSerial()** function which in turn calls the **transfer()** function from `Domain` contract (as shown in code) the transaction fails because it is trying to send funds from the `Serial` contract's address and not my wallet.

Is there way to modify **payToSerial()** function to cuurumvent this?

//

//

//

I tried to edit **payToSerial()** to accomplish that (To inherent msg.sender), but it did not work.

```
function payToSerial(string memory serialNumber, uint amount) public {

    DOMAIN = Domain(msg.sender);
    address toAddr = serialAddresses[serialNumber];
    DOMAIN.transfer(toAddr, amount);
}
```

I am not sure if what I am trying to do is even possible, but I wanted to ask in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I found this tutorial video explaining Delegatecall for Solidity 0.8. This was what I needed

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uawCDnxFJ-0

Comment: If Domain were an ERC-20 token you could use the `transferFrom` function. The token's owner must approve beforehand for it to work. See this question for the difference between transfer and transferFrom https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46457/send-tokens-using-approve-and-transferfrom-vs-only-transfer.

Answer (score 0):

**The obstacle:**

No one can create a contract that spends from someone else's wallet. This rule doesn't change when two contracts originate from the same author.

**The solution:**

There is a trust relationship between the two contracts. Domain cannot spend from Serial's money, but Serial can give Domain money for a specific purpose with an expectation that unused funds will be returned.

"Here's $10. Go to the store and buy me ____, if they have any, and bring me back my change." - codify the rules in Domain's function.

You'll see money going from Serial to Domain, and back (it says "conditional"). It might cause you to reconsider how you modularize your application. In this situation, the key is everyone has to spend from the funds they have in hand.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. But I think my question might have been poorly made. I edited it now to further clarify my problem and what is going on.