# DelegateCall returning false

Tags: solidity, truffle, delegatecall

I'm learning Solidity and tried to create a couple of contracts on Truffle.

For this, I have created a Shop.sol contract that can "Buy" items using an ERC20 token.
Inside the buyItem() function I use delegateCall, but it always returns false, and I don't get to spot the problem.

When the buyItem() function is called by the sender, I would like the Shop contract to directly manage the Erc20 token fund transfer in order to buy the item.

I'm running this test from a truffle Test.

The deploy_contracts.js file:

```
var PoToken = artifacts.require("./PoToken.sol");
var Shop = artifacts.require("./Shop.sol");

module.exports = async function(deployer) {
  await deployer.deploy(PoToken,1000000);
  console.log(PoToken.address);
  await deployer.deploy(Shop,PoToken.address);
};
```

The Shop.sol contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;

import "./Interfaces/IShop.sol";
import "./PoToken.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
/**
 * @dev Interface representing a virtual Shop.
 */
contract Shop is IShop, Ownable {

   
    // Structure of an item. This should be changed lately with a ERC721 or similar NFT.
    struct Item {
        uint256 id;
        uint256 weight;
        string name;
        uint256 value;
    }

    // Owned items by owner.
    // Items on address(0) can be bought by customers.
    mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => Item)) public ownedItems;

    // @devs Total number of items;
    uint256 private _itemsCount;

    address private _poTokenContractAddress;


    constructor (address poTokenContract) {
        _itemsCount = 1;

        _poTokenContractAddress = poTokenContract;
    }

     function buyItem(uint256 itemId, uint256 amountPaid) external override returns (bool) {

        // check that the item is available (on address(0))
        require(ownedItems[address(0)][itemId].id == itemId, "The selected item is not available.");

        // Check if the amountPaid is enough to buy the item.
        require(amountPaid == ownedItems[address(0)][itemId].value,"The sent amount has to be equal to the item value");

        // Substract sent value from user PO total
        // FIXME FIX DELEGATECALL ALWAYS RETURN FALSE
        (bool transferSucceded, )  = _poTokenContractAddress.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount)", owner(),amountPaid));

        require(transferSucceded == true, "The Payment failed");
        // Buy the item, updating the mapping
        ownedItems[msg.sender][itemId] = ownedItems[address(0)][itemId];

        // delete the item held by the shop.
        delete(ownedItems[address(0)][itemId]);

        // Emit Event and return
        emit itemBoughtEvent(msg.sender, itemId, amountPaid);

        return true;
     }
}
```

The ShopTests.js

```
    it("buy a product", async () => {

        // Get accounts
        const [ initialHolder, recipient, anotherAccount ] = accounts;

        // Deploy contract
        const poTokenInstance = await poTokenStorage.deployed();
        const shopContractInstance = await shopContract.deployed();

        // Then
        // Give tokens to testing user
        await shopContractInstance.addItem("Flaming Bastard Sword", 5, 8400,{from : initialHolder});

        await poTokenInstance.transfer(recipient,8400);
        const obj = await shopContractInstance.buyItem(1, 8400,{from : recipient});
        
        // expect
        assert.equal(obj,true,"The item name doesnt match");
    });
```

The test fails with the require on Shop.sol:49, because the delegateCall returned value is false.

```
1) Contract: Shop
       buy a product:
     Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert The Payment failed -- Reason given: The Payment failed.
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/ShopTest.js:41:48)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

I would appreciate any ideas :). You can find the code on this repository: [git repository](https://github.com/damoklesh/SkylarShop)

Comment: You can't use delegatecall for that task. Delegatecall doesn't change the contract storage, nor msg.sender it just changes the bytecode. When the Shop contract delegatecall the Token it will execute the Token over the Shop storage. The best case is that it reverts because it isn't accessing the Token data, the worst case is that you get silent data corruption in Shop contract.

Comment: Thanks Ismael for your answer, I think that I understand the storage problem. Is there any other way for calling the ERC20 transfer function from the Shop contract? is this possible at all?

Comment: No, you just have to use the regular calls. You have to use something like this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46457/send-tokens-using-approve-and-transferfrom-vs-only-transfer.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I understand better the approve() and transferFrom() pattern. Thank you very much Ismael and happy new year.