# How to transfer my ERC20 token correctly?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20

I have my `ExampleToken` contract from Openzeppelin:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import 'https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol';

contract ExampleToken is ERC20 {

    address public owner;

    constructor() ERC20('ExampleToken', 'EXM') {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000 * 10**18);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
}
```

And I want my other contract to manage those tokens.
I was trying to create function which will send 100 of my `ExampleToken` to anyone who call this function.
And even if remix output showed that transaction was correct, I couldn't see any balance changes either on my contract balance, or `msg.sender` balance.

Here is my other contract:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import './ExampleToken.sol';

contract MyContract {

    address public owner;
    uint public EXMbalance;
    ExampleToken public exampleToken;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
        exampleToken = new ExampleToken();
        EXMbalance = exampleToken.balanceOf(address(this));
    }

    function getBalanceOf(address adr) public view returns(uint) {
        return exampleToken.balanceOf(adr) / 10**18;
    }

    function contractBalance() public view returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance ;
    }

    function requestEXM(uint quantity) public {
        require(quantity <= 100 && quantity > 0);

        exampleToken.approve(address(this), quantity);
        exampleToken.transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, quantity);
        EXMbalance -= quantity;
    }

    function invest() external payable {

    }

}
```

Output in remix when I call `requestEXM` function:
[image]

Comment: Take a look at his answer that explain how transfer and transferFrom work https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/46458/

Comment: @Ismael
I actually moved from ```transfer``` function to ```transferFrom``` cause it seemed like it's not working too, I couldn't see balance of my coin, it was still 0. 
Now I realized that I was sending 100 WEI and I was reading the balance converted to ETH (* 10**18).

I moved back to ```transfer``` function, fixed the converting problem, and it's working fine. Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice if you could add the resulting fix as answer so the question can be marked as resolved.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that, I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was that function `requestEXM` is transfering 100 in WEI and my reading balance function `getBalanceOf` is returning value in ETHER, so that was the reason why I saw the 0 balance at first place using `.transfer` and then `.transferFrom` function of ERC20 contract.

As was mentioned above there's no need for `approve` function, and `transferFrom` function as it's not 3rd party transfer.

So the proper way of transferring tokens in this case could be like this:

```
function requestEXM(uint quantity) public {
        
        require(quantity <= 100 && quantity > 0);

        exampleToken.transfer(msg.sender, quantity * 10**18);
        EXMbalance -= quantity * 10**18;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First the requestEXM function does not make sense. This line

`exampleToken.approve(address(this), quantity);`

Tries to approve your contract to spend `quantity` tokens which is not required. Your contract is the owner of it's tokens, your contract doesn't need any approval to spend it's own tokens.

Comment: Yes, I moved back to ```transfer``` function.
It's working now, I was converting balance from WEI to ETHER with ```* 10**18```, which was the reason why I didn't see the balance.