# ERC721 transferring NFTs and currency

Tags: erc-20, erc-721, transfer, erc-20-approve

I have a contract that I want to use as an NFT marketplace.  It extends ERC721URIStorage

`contract NftMarketplace is ERC721URIStorage ...`

In on function I use _transfer() to move an NFT from the seller to the buyer.  Do I need to call "approve" or "approveForAll" first before using this?  In my hardhat tests, there is no error using _transfer, but I don't know how to check my test accounts to see if the NFT actually moved.

My second question is about approving transfers of funds by a buyer in advance.  The use case for this is the buyer making a bid or offer of a certain amount, and then the contract processing the payment later.  I see this can be done by extending ERC20 contracts...but how can I bring that functionality into my contract that extends ERC721?  Can I extends two contracts?  Is that the best way?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is NftMarketplace inheriting from ERC721URIStorage? You are making the marketplace an ERC721 by itself.

Comment: actually im following a tutorial. i did notice that and it seemed odd.

Comment: Usually methods with underscore are private/internal and shouldn't be used when calling methods from another contract. To move tokens from a different contract you should use `transfer` or `transferFrom` depending on the situation, see this answer for an explanation https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/46458.

Comment: to clarify, this is using _transfer to move tokens minted by the same contract, however those tokens are currently not owned by the contract.