# How to spend a specific amount of ether and send it to the smart contract (from msg sender)?

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets, solidity-0.8.x

i am able to send eth (with a payable function ) to the my contract but what i really need is that when the user interact with the contract it takes a specific amount on the msg sender and add it to its balance.

Comment: A contract cannot withdraw ether from other addresses. It can only withdraw from its own balance. You can achieve something similar using ERC20 function transferFrom. See this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/46458/ to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The sender must attach the required amount of ETH to the transaction.

```
mywallet.sendTransaction({to: contractAddress, value: "1000000000"})
```

Contract will then be receiving this amount as part of the transaction.

Comment: so if i understand  i do `msg.sender.sendTransaction({to: contractAddress, value: "1000000000"})` do i need to import any library for this function sendTransaction ?

Comment: No, that's just an example of how to send value to a contract.

Comment: but how should i define that sendTransaction function ?