# What is this STF error when trying to use a function in a contract

Tags: solidity, remix, kovan

I know there are many similiar questions but i can not figure out how to implement the 'approve' part in.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;
pragma abicoder v2;

import '@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/libraries/TransferHelper.sol';
import '@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol';

contract SwapExamples {
    // For the scope of these swap examples,
    // we will detail the design considerations when using
    // `exactInput`, `exactInputSingle`, `exactOutput`, and  `exactOutputSingle`.

    // It should be noted that for the sake of these examples, we purposefully pass in the swap router instead of inherit the swap router for simplicity.
    // More advanced example contracts will detail how to inherit the swap router safely.

    ISwapRouter public immutable swapRouter;

    // This example swaps DAI/WETH9 for single path swaps and DAI/USDC/WETH9 for multi path swaps.

    address public constant DAI = 0xDA10009cBd5D07dd0CeCc66161FC93D7c9000da1;
    address public constant WETH9 = 0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000006;
    address public constant USDC = 0x4e62882864fB8CE54AFfcAf8D899A286762B011B;

    // For this example, we will set the pool fee to 0.3%.
    uint24 public constant poolFee = 3000;

    constructor(ISwapRouter _swapRouter) {
        swapRouter = _swapRouter;
    }

    /// @notice swapExactInputSingle swaps a fixed amount of DAI for a maximum possible amount of WETH9
    /// using the DAI/WETH9 0.3% pool by calling `exactInputSingle` in the swap router.
    /// @dev The calling address must approve this contract to spend at least `amountIn` worth of its DAI for this function to succeed.
    /// @param amountIn The exact amount of DAI that will be swapped for WETH9.
    /// @return amountOut The amount of WETH9 received.
    function swapExactInputSingle(uint256 amountIn) external returns (uint256 amountOut) {
        // msg.sender must approve this contract

        // Transfer the specified amount of DAI to this contract.
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(DAI, msg.sender, address(this), amountIn);

        // Approve the router to spend DAI.
        TransferHelper.safeApprove(DAI, address(swapRouter), amountIn);

        // Naively set amountOutMinimum to 0. In production, use an oracle or other data source to choose a safer value for amountOutMinimum.
        // We also set the sqrtPriceLimitx96 to be 0 to ensure we swap our exact input amount.
        ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params =
            ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams({
                tokenIn: DAI,
                tokenOut: WETH9,
                fee: poolFee,
                recipient: msg.sender,
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountIn: amountIn,
                amountOutMinimum: 0,
                sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
            });

        // The call to `exactInputSingle` executes the swap.
        amountOut = swapRouter.exactInputSingle(params);
    }

    /// @notice swapExactOutputSingle swaps a minimum possible amount of DAI for a fixed amount of WETH.
    /// @dev The calling address must approve this contract to spend its DAI for this function to succeed. As the amount of input DAI is variable,
    /// the calling address will need to approve for a slightly higher amount, anticipating some variance.
    /// @param amountOut The exact amount of WETH9 to receive from the swap.
    /// @param amountInMaximum The amount of DAI we are willing to spend to receive the specified amount of WETH9.
    /// @return amountIn The amount of DAI actually spent in the swap.
    function swapExactOutputSingle(uint256 amountOut, uint256 amountInMaximum) external returns (uint256 amountIn) {
        // Transfer the specified amount of DAI to this contract.
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(DAI, msg.sender, address(this), amountInMaximum);

        // Approve the router to spend the specifed `amountInMaximum` of DAI.
        // In production, you should choose the maximum amount to spend based on oracles or other data sources to acheive a better swap.
        TransferHelper.safeApprove(DAI, address(swapRouter), amountInMaximum);

        ISwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams memory params =
            ISwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams({
                tokenIn: DAI,
                tokenOut: WETH9,
                fee: poolFee,
                recipient: msg.sender,
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountOut: amountOut,
                amountInMaximum: amountInMaximum,
                sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
            });

        // Executes the swap returning the amountIn needed to spend to receive the desired amountOut.
        amountIn = swapRouter.exactOutputSingle(params);

        // For exact output swaps, the amountInMaximum may not have all been spent.
        // If the actual amount spent (amountIn) is less than the specified maximum amount, we must refund the msg.sender and approve the swapRouter to spend 0.
        if (amountIn < amountInMaximum) {
            TransferHelper.safeApprove(DAI, address(swapRouter), 0);
            TransferHelper.safeTransfer(DAI, msg.sender, amountInMaximum - amountIn);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my error:

```
Gas estimation failed
Close
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted: STF" }
```

Comment: What is the "approve part" ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Trying to let the contract take some DAI from my metamask wallet but i supposedly need to approve the contract

Comment: @CloudTrauma Do you have the failed transaction hash? Usually to use transferFrom the owner has to call approve first, see the details here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/46458/.

Answer (score 3):

`execution reverted: STF` means execution is reverted by `require` assertion in `TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom` function.

Here is the code of Uniswap V3 Swap Router https://etherscan.io/address/0xe592427a0aece92de3edee1f18e0157c05861564#code

If you search this code for "STF", you'll find the implementation:

```
  function safeTransferFrom(
        address token,
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 value
    ) internal {
        (bool success, bytes memory data) =
            token.call(abi.encodeWithSelector(IERC20.transferFrom.selector, from, to, value));
        require(success && (data.length == 0 || abi.decode(data, (bool))), 'STF');
    }
```

Possible cause of this can be simply not enough DAI tokens on `msg.sender`

Answer (score 0):

Your error code is most likely attributed to not having the smart contract approved to access your DAI tokens.

This must be done MANUALLY, e.g. via Metamask or in a Node.Js file as follows:

```
const { ethers } = require('ethers')
require('dotenv').config()

// save the abi file locally and call it
const ERC20ABI = require('../data/erc20.json')

// Token addresses for Ropsten
const DAI = "0xaD6D458402F60fD3Bd25163575031ACDce07538D"

// import from .env file
const INFURA = process.env.INFURA_ROPSTEN
const WALLET_ADDRESS = process.env.WALLET_ADDRESS
const WALLET_SECRET = process.env.WALLET_SECRET

// input here your deployed contract
const SmartContractAddress = '0x......'

// initiate wallet with private key
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(INFURA)
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(WALLET_SECRET)
const connectedWallet = wallet.connect(provider)

// initiate ERC20 contract
const DAIcontract = new ethers.Contract(
    DAI,
    ERC20ABI,
    provider
)

// function to approve token
const approve = async (ERC20contract, toApproveAddress) => {
    ERC20contract.connect(connectedWallet).approve(
        toApproveAddress,
        ethers.utils.parseEther("1").toString(),
        {
            gasLimit: ethers.utils.hexlify(1000000)
        }
    ).then(transaction => {
        console.log(transaction)
    })
}


async function main() {
    approve(DAIcontract, SmartContractAddress)
}

main()
```