# How to use TransferFrom function?

Tags: solidity, transactions, erc-20, openzeppelin

Im currently creating a DEX where users swap tokens. However I have to use IERC20 transferfrom( address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount). But for this to happen the 3rd party(1inch)  will need permission to approve and withdraw.

**Questions/Problems:**

1. What address should be sender/from? -(mine or 1inch?)
2. what address should be the recipient/to?- (mine or 1inch?)
3. _tokenAddress is token that the user wants. Is this correct?

```
**My Current Code:**

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";


contract testTransfer{
using SafeMath for uint256;
mapping(address => uint) balances;
 

address private Commowner = payable (0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2) ;// account that take commission
 uint256 public commission = 1;  // we want 1%

function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint amount, address _tokenAddress )  public payable {

uint fee =  amount  * commission / 10000; // we want 1%


  // 0x11 is 1inch (sender/from),  msg.sender/account (to) the address trying to recieve tokens, 1 is the amount,
  //_tokenAddress the erc20 token that we want.
  IERC20(_tokenAddress).transferFrom(from, to, amount);

   balances[from] = balances[from].sub(fee);
    balances[Commowner] = balances[Commowner].add(fee); // we get the commission.
 // emit transfer(from,to,value);

}}
```

Thanks for your help
Dee

Comment: Read the `transferFrom` behavior https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46457/send-tokens-using-approve-and-transferfrom-vs-only-transfer. In some cases you need to use `transfer` and in other cases `transferFrom`.

Comment: Thanks Ismael for responding , I've read the the info in the link you posted. However my main question is just using the transferFrom it will allow a 3rd party to withdraw but what if a user/customer want to swap an erc20 token for another erc20 token I wouldn't just use transferFrom by itself. or can it? @Ismael